# Scrapy Next Page Button and Previous Page Button are on the same class, can't reach the next page

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape one dictionary. Which has next page and previous page buttons. When I try to reach next page("Sonraki Sayfa") with this way

```
next_page = response.css('div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-6 a::attr(href)').get()
```

I always reach the previous page button because they have same class names.

This is the html code of website:

```
<ul class="sayfalama">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <a href="kelimeler.php?s=-1" style="background: white; font-weight: bold; padding:5px;">Önceki Sayfa</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <a href="kelimeler.php?s=1" style="background: white; font-weight: bold; padding:5px;">Sonraki Sayfa</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</ul>
```

This is my code of spider

```
next_page = response.css('div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-6 a::attr(href)').get()
print(next_page)

if next_page is not None:

  yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

What should change to reach next page(Sonraki Sayfa) instead of previous page( Onceki Sayfa)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `nth-child`. like below:

```
next_page = response.css('div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-6:nth-child(2) a::attr(href)').get()
```

```css
div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-6:nth-child(2) a {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <a href="kelimeler.php?s=-1" style="background: white; font-weight: bold; padding:5px;">Önceki Sayfa</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <a href="kelimeler.php?s=1">Sonraki Sayfa</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Also, the website has 146 pages with words but after page 146 the last page is showing again. So, if next_page is not None: is not working. Do you have any suggestion for that?

Comment: you can ask another question for that.

Comment: I asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024356/scrapy-last-page-is-not-null-and-after-page-146-last-page-is-showing-again