# Scrapy Last Page is not null and after page 146 last page is showing again

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy, css-selectors

The website has 146 pages with words but after page 146 the last page is showing again.
`

```
     if next_page is not None:

         yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)`
```

With this method sprider is not stoping at page 146 and it continues because page 147,148,149..is same as page 146. I tried to use for loop but that not worked. Also, I tried to take the value in next page button and break the function with next_extract. By the way output of next_extract is ['kelimeler.php?s=1']and the number increases with the page number like ['kelimeler.php?s=2']. Also, this way is not worked.

```
         next_page = response.css('div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-6:nth-child(2) a::attr(href)').get()
     next_extract = response.css('div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-6:nth-child(2) a').xpath("@href").extract()

     print(next_page)
     print(next_extract)




     
     if next_extract is 'kelimeler.php?s=147':
         break
     if next_page is not None:
         yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

What should I do to stop the scrapying at page 146?

That's the whole parse function

```
     def parse(self,response):

     items = TidtutorialItem()

     all_div_kelimeler = response.css('a.collapsed')

     for tid in all_div_kelimeler:

         kelime = tid.css('a.collapsed::text').extract()
         link= tid.css('a.collapsed::text').xpath("@href").extract()


         items['Kelime'] = kelime
         items['Link'] = link

         yield items

     next_page = response.css('div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-6:nth-child(2) a::attr(href)').get()
     next_extract = response.css('div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-6:nth-child(2) a').xpath("@href").extract()

     print(next_page)
     print(next_extract)


     if next_page is not None:
     #if next_extract is not 'kelimeler.php?s=2':
     #for i in range (10):
         yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be very precise about the best approach without seeing the page, but I can giv you some suggestions.

```
     next_page = response.css('div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-6:nth-child(2) a::attr(href)').get()
     next_extract = response.css('div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-6:nth-child(2) a').xpath("@href").extract()
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here, as both the selectors are essentially the same, except that the second one you are using the `.extract()` method, which returns a **LIST**. And since it returns a list this following line will **ALWAYS** fail:

```
    if next_extract is 'kelimeler.php?s=147':
        break
```

Another important point is that `break` is meant to be used inside a loop, so if the *if statement* ever resolved into `True`, this would cause an exception. Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Again, without seeing the page I can't say this for sure, but I believe this would acomplish what you are trying to do:

```
    if next_page == 'kelimeler.php?s=147':
         return
```

*Notice `next_page` instead of `next_extract`. If you want to use the latter, remember it is a list, not a string.*

Comment: The answer is worked. Also, thank you for explanation and information about break.